# Data type that rounds .(9) to 1 automatically?

Tags: c#, math, decimal

I'm trying to find solutions to a simple MDAS (i.e. Multiplication, Division...) problem using C#, and while it mostly gets correct solutions, I have problems when the variables add up to x.99999... so I get wrong answers because it doesn't compute to 1.

For example, if I have:

```
        decimal a = 1M;
        decimal b = 2M;
        decimal c = 6M;
        decimal d = 4M;
        decimal e = 7M;
        decimal f = 8M;
        decimal g = 3M;
        decimal h = 5M;
        decimal i = 9M;
        Console.WriteLine(a + 13 * b / c + d + 12 * e - f - 11);
        Console.WriteLine(g * h / i);
        Console.WriteLine(a + 13 * b / c + d + 12 * e - f - 11 + g * h / i);
```

Which gives me:

```
74.33333333333333333333333333
1.6666666666666666666666666667
75.999999999999999999999999997
```

But I want:

```
74.33333333333333333333333333
1.6666666666666666666666666667
76
```

Is there a way that I can always get a precise answer to .(6)+.(3) = 1 without needing to check and modify the values? If not what is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Create your own `Rational` number type which internally stores integer numerator and denominators and performs operations on those, only performing the actual division computation when absolutely required.

Comment: Or use some NuGet package http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/rational

Comment: Also, rounding. There's numbers you simply can't represent as a finite binary (or decimal) number. Unless you have strong precision requirements, it might very well be fine enough to just do `Math.Round` once in a while, with the required precision. If you do care about exact precision, rational numbers are the way to go. Assuming you're only doing operations you can represent in rational numbers - no `log`, `sqrt` etc. Otherwise you're still left with rounding :)

Comment: @tia Thanks for everyone's comments, but I went with tia 's easiest-way solution (NuGet). Hahaha. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with @tia and Dai's suggestion to use a Rational data type. I got [tompazourek's Rationals NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Rationals/) and used it like this:

```
        Rational a = 1;
        Rational b = 2;
        Rational c = 6;
        Rational d = 4;
        Rational e = 7;
        Rational f = 8;
        Rational g = 3;
        Rational h = 5;
        Rational i = 9;
        Console.WriteLine(a + (Rational)13 * b / c + d + (Rational)12 * e - f - (Rational)11);
        Console.WriteLine(g * h / i);
        Rational toTest = a + (Rational)13 * b / c + d + (Rational)12 * e - f - (Rational)11 + g * h / i;
        Console.WriteLine(toTest);
        Console.WriteLine(toTest.Equals(76));
```

Which gives me:

```
446/6
15/9
4104/54
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will round your `double` value to within a precision of 0.1:

```
// parameters
double d = -7.9;
double precision = 0.1;

//the conversion
double v = (Math.Abs(Math.Round(d)-d)) < precision ? Math.Round(d) : d;

//output
int i = (int) v;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: That's too imprecise (.1) for my purposes, and I wouldn't really use a double for this particular problem (I rarely use it, to be honest, because I usually work with precise numbers). Thanks for your answer anyway!